# selecting a set of objects based on index linq

Tags: arrays, linq, select, indexing

Is there any way to select, from an array of for example 2000 elements, all the elements between the 100th(included) and the 200th(excluded) element without creating your own row index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var pageItems = array.Skip(99).Take(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] myArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 2000).ToArray();
myArray = myArray.Where((source, index) => index >= 100 && index <= 200).ToArray();
```

you can see the the full csharppad here http://csharppad.com/gist/5cfc902bbe4e5e8b4a3d85826d64170f